# Free software for interactive panoramas?

Tags: photography, panorama

Is there any free software to create interactive panoramas (360º, like [this one](http://viewat.org/?hd=1&i=pl&sec=pn&id_pn=3272)) in Ubuntu?

**Edit:**  I would need not only a way to create a *static* panorama (i.e, a JPG file, for instance), but also a way to convert it to some interactive format (swf, mov....) or some way to implement it in a web page so that it can be panned, rotated, etc. (zoomed would also be nice, but is not strictly required).

Comment: Are you looking for a program to make the panorama images (like Hugin) or a tool to display/view them on the web?

Comment: Both of them, or a tool that can do both things in one single step.... But, anyway, I'd need to know the complete workflow from the pictures (already taken) to the interactive panorama (i.e. click and drag to move, or something similar).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/)  ( [Click To Install](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/hugin) )

[image]

> Hugin is a panorama photo stitching program. Essentially, Hugin is a GUI frontend for Panorama Tools. Stitching is accomplished by using several overlapping photos taken from the same location, and using control points to align and transform the photos so that they can be blended together to form a larger image. Hugin allows for the easy creation of control points between two images, optimization of the image transforms, and much more.

Comment: OK. Installed. Got my panorama. But now I need to add the "interactivity" stuff. As it's for a web page... is there any kind of free jpg>swf converter for this purpose or any free java applet that somehow makes the panorama "browsable"?

Comment: Tagged it as accepted answer, because it's close to what I need.... but still  don't have a way to 'publish' the panoramas I create in a web with some kind of interactive features...

Comment: luri, did you ever solve the interactive part?